# InvalidOperationException on XP but not Windows 10

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to run my Winforms application on an XP machine but getting the following error. It works fine when running on Windows 10. Form2 is initiated when Form1 is minimized, but Form2 should not display if a process named SomeApplication is running. Can someone please help me figure out what XP might not be liking about this code? Also, even on Windows 10, this form causes high CPU usage, possibly owing to the use of the thread? Anyone have a better way doing this?

```
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.InvalidOperationException
Stack:
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.MarshaledInvoke(System.Windows.Forms.Control, System.Delegate, System.Object[], Boolean)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.Invoke(System.Delegate, System.Object[])
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.Invoke(System.Delegate)
   at NotificationCenter.Form2.checkThread()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()




 public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.TopMost = true;
            this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
            Thread th = new Thread(checkThread);
            th.Start();
        }

           public void checkThread()
           {
           while (true)
           {
               var pname = Process.GetProcessesByName("SomeApplication");
               if (pname.Length > 0)
               {
                   Invoke(new Action(() =>
                   {
                       this.Visible = false;
                   }));
               }
           else
           {
              Invoke(new Action(() =>
              {
                  this.Visible = true;

              }));
             }}}

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {   
                Form1 settingsForm = new Form1();
                settingsForm.Show();         
            }
```

And here is Form1 calling upon Form2:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
            this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
            this.Hide();
            this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;


            Form fc = Application.OpenForms["Form2"];
           if (fc != null)
            {

            }
           else
           {
               Form2 settingsForm = new Form2();
               settingsForm.Show();
               settingsForm.TopMost = true;
               settingsForm.ShowInTaskbar = false;
           }
        }

EDIT:
Solved the issue by changing the code below:

public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {


           InitializeComponent();
                this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
                int intScreenHeight = 

           Convert.ToInt32(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height * .002);
                int intScreenWidth = 
           Convert.ToInt32(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width * .95);
                this.Location = new Point(intScreenWidth, 
           intScreenHeight);
                this.TopMost = true;
                this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
                this.MinimumSize = new Size(1, 1);
                this.Size = new Size(54, 44);
                int intButtonYSize = ClientSize.Height;
                int intButtonXSize = ClientSize.Width;
                button1.Size = new Size(intButtonXSize, intButtonYSize);
          //      Thread th = new Thread(checkThread);
          //      th.Start();


                Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    while (true)
                    {
                        var pname = 
               Process.GetProcessesByName("SomeApplication");
                        if (pname.Length > 0)
                        {
                            Invoke(new Action(() =>
                            {
                                this.Visible = false;
                            }));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Invoke(new Action(() =>
                            {
                                this.Visible = true;
                            }));
                        }
                    }
                });           
            }

            private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {   
                Form1 settingsForm = new Form1();
                settingsForm.Show();                                          
            }

            private void label2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                Form1 settingsForm = new Form1();
                settingsForm.Show();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Not sure about your issue, but changing form properties like WindowState, FormBorderStyle, TopMost and ShowInTaskbar should only be done in the form's constructor.  Otherwise, Windows needs to destroy the window and rebuild it.

Comment: My first question would be: why are you still developing applications for an outdated OS which MS dropped support 5 years ago

Comment: @LarsTech, thanks for pointing that out, I cleaned that up. The only ones I had to leave were the WindowState since that needs to be changed (minimized) upon the button click event.

Comment: @Steve, because we still have XP machines around that we need to support.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, WindowState does not force a window destruction.  Got a bit zealous in my property listing.

Comment: Errors with XP get resolved when using Task factory. However, it does have extremely high CPU usage. Any suggestions on what might be causing that or avoiding that?